# User session and https

Tags: users, sessions, cookies, ssl

I've got a few pages on my site that need to be accessed via https.
I need to pull some information about the current logged user on those pages.
The problem is, users log using http mode and the session is not kept when switching from http to https.
I've looked into secure login module but it brings some other issues (with facebook connect...)

Is there any way we can tell the cookie to persist ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using secure pages or similar module?

Answer (score 1):

Add `$conf['https'] = TRUE;` to `settings.php`.

from here:
http://drupal.org/node/1037542
and 
http://drupal.org/https-information

however, why not just run the whole site securely?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added $conf['https'] = TRUE; my session is still lost between http and https, it's actuall killing my session. Once I click on a https link and come back to http, my session is lost.

Comment: This is a good read: http://drupal.org/node/1131986

you could hack in a function to copy the sessions `sid` value to `ssid`, but I don't think that's a good idea due to security concerns.